# R find unduplicated rows based on other data's columns

Tags: r, duplicates, data-manipulation

I have a question about finding unduplicated rows based on another data's columns.
I know there are many reference to remove and find duplicated rows on one data, like `dt[duplicated(dt)]` or `dt[!duplicated(dt)]`.
However, if I want to find or remove duplicated rows based on other data, how can I do?

```
# dt1
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD
TA43     S2230   Amy     2014-08-08
TA63     T1205   Andy    2014-01-01
TI28     L1288   Peter   2014-01-08
TI28     L2231   Roger   2014-01-08
TI92     A2206   Jean    2014-01-03
TI14     E2240   Freda   2014-01-05
TI69     N1029   Tina    2014-01-05

# dt2
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD
TA63     T1205   Andy    2014-01-01
TA86     L1288   Peter   2014-01-08
TA86     L2231   Roger   2014-01-08
TA93     A2206   Jean    2014-01-12
TA41     E2240   Freda   2014-01-05
TI69     N1029   Tina    2014-01-05
```

What I want is those unduplicated rows.

```
# new dt1  
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD
TA43     S2230   Amy     2014-08-08
TI28     L1288   Peter   2014-01-08
TI28     L2231   Roger   2014-01-08
TI92     A2206   Jean    2014-01-03
TI14     E2240   Freda   2014-01-05

# new dt2    
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD
TA86     L1288   Peter   2014-01-08
TA86     L2231   Roger   2014-01-08
TA93     A2206   Jean    2014-01-12
TA41     E2240   Freda   2014-01-05
```

**UPDATE**
I attach the answer here.

```
dt1[!dt2, on = c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD")]

dt2[!dt1, on = c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD")]
```

Comment: try `anti_join` from the `dplyr` package